# How to run unittest tests using coverage API

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am trying to generate a coverage report using the `coverage`-API (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.3.2/api.html#api).

The simple use-case described on the linked page tells me to wrap my executed code inside the snippet they provide. I am using `unittest.main()` to execute tests. The below code runs without an error but neither is any report information created nor is `print("Done.")` executed.

I guess `unittest.main()` calls a `sys.exit()` somewhere along the way? How does one use the API to execute all unittest-tests?

### Example

```
import coverage
import unittest


def func(input):
    return input


class testInput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(func(1), 1)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cov = coverage.Coverage()
    cov.start()

    unittest.main()

    cov.stop()
    cov.save()

    cov.html_report()
    print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like unittest.main() is calling sys.exit().  Are you sure you need to use the coverage API? You can skip coverage and most of unittest:

```py
# foo.py
import unittest


def func(input):
    return input


class testInput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(func(1), 1)
```

Then:

```
$ python -m coverage run -m unittest foo.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

$ python -m coverage report -m
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------
foo.py       6      0   100%
--------------------------------------
TOTAL        6      0   100%
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. There are some intricacies to my dev environment, that would make me prefer the option I have described in the original post, but this will do. In any way - thank you for your tremendous contribution to the python community!

Answer (score 0):

To get the example to work you can simply put the call to `unittest.main()` in a try/except statement so the `cov.stop()` will be called once the unit test has completed.

```
# testInput.py
import coverage
import unittest

def func(input):
    return input

class testInput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(func(1), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cov = coverage.Coverage()
    cov.start()

    try:
        unittest.main()
    except:  # catch-all except clause
        pass

    cov.stop()
    cov.save()

    cov.html_report()
    print("Done.")
```

This will run as desired, including printing `Done.` at the end:

```
python3 testInput.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Done.
```

The HTML coverage report will have been created in the `htmlcov` directory in the current working directory.